# How to associate Driver with scene active camera?

Tags: animation, camera, drivers

I've got two cameras in my scene.

When they are switching via timeline markers, *Driver* which is based on distance between some object and camera1 goes crazy, because at this point I am filming with camera2.

Can I perform switch from camera1 to camera2 inside *Driver* in the same time, as cameras are switching on the timeline?

[image]

Comment: Could you provide more details, perhaps a sample file with basic setup? A [frame change handler](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.app.handlers.html?#basic-handler-example) on the scene may be a better solution.

Comment: I've uploaded basic scene.